# Return NULL columns if IDs don't exist in the table

Tags: sql-server

I have one solution with left join for the below question, but I'm looking for more efficient query

```
Select * from table1 where Id in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

returns all the existing "Ids" in the table. Now I want all the Ids to be returned with null columns if the Id is not existing in the table.

EX: Result must contain 3 and 5 though the IDs not existing in the table

```
ID  Name  Designation
1   John   Employee
2   Nar    Manager
3   **NULL**   **NULL**
4   Esh    Executive.
5   **NULL**   **NULL**
```

Comment: There is probably no way to do this more efficiently than with a LEFT OUTER JOIN. I have to ask; what exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps this is something that belongs on the programming rather than in an SQL query. Smells that way. :)

Comment: What flavor of SQL are we talking about? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? Something else...?

Comment: Its SQL Server flavor, Im using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select x.id, y.name, y.designation
from (
select row_number() OVER(order by id) as id
from table1
) x
left join table1 y
on x.id = y.id
```

This ought to work.

Comment: My query will always get the IDs dynamically.